External switch and socket enclosed in a waterproof enclosure blew its pilot light when testing without load
I have an external switch with a pilot light and a plug point enclosed in a Legrand Plexo waterproof enclosure. We had very heavy rains recently and today I switched on the switch to check the condition of the switch and its associated socket with no load attached. To my surprise I could hear sputtering inside with smoke coming out. After opening, I didn't find any damage except that the pilot light had burned off.I found the wiring was burnt near the connection to LED probably due to the short. I checked the sockets with a multimeter and I find a healthy 234V without any issues (Socket and switch is rated 16A,230V). I also checked the insides of the metal box and I did not find any moisture as such. What could have caused this problem?

Pilot LIght in an enclosure with 230V?  What country is this in>  It doesn't sound like any N. American scenario.

It sounds like one or more wire connections were/are loose.  Loose connections cause extra resistance and heat that might lead lead to burning.  North America codes now require using torque drivers for most(if not all) wire connections.

16A 230V is pretty normal for most of the rest of the planet.

@RMDman: Country is India. Pilot light here means the indicator light on the switch.

@crip659: The wire damage happened near the indicator side of the wiring and not towards the terminals of the socket. Reference photo of the switch: https://vashiisl.com/products/legrand-673010-16a-1way-1module-switch-with-indicator-250v
Was the wire near the indicator strained? Would condensation have affected in some way?

Condensation might have corroded or shorted out a connection.  Corrosion  would/should have taken a few years before being noticed, since most people do not check until it goes poof.

@crip659:  How does one safely test whether water is not going in? Also can such things be avoided?

Likely some water got in and caused the short, then the arcing from that short caused more damage. Not finding residual water may simply mean that most of it was boiled off in the ensuing "smoke," some of which might have been steam.
Alternatively, the component in question might have been defective as made and simply happened to fail at that point in time. If it came from abroad and lacks local safety agency markings that's the more likely root cause, as dodgy "self-imported" junk that gets past local regulations is highly suspect.
In North America we'd require that such a circuit be protected by a GFCI (a close relative of the RCD you may have, but more sensitive.) That would not prevent an arc from line to neutral, but would shut down if more than 5mA went to Ground (Earth.)

I have RCD for my 6A circuits. All 6A and 16A are connected to breakers. I thought with this short would trip my break but it did not.
Would condensation cause this problem?
